# Access credential information from soap header in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I need to access user name and password from the soap header inside php script. I can access the body information but could not access the header information.
Here is the SOAp...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"        xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext" 
xmlns:met="http://www.example.com/data">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sec:Security>
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>ron</Username>            
            <Password>pass</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
      </sec:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <met:columnInfo>
         <databaseName>MySQL</adaptorName>        
         <tableName>product</tableName>
      </met:columnInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found the solution for that.

```
$server = new SoapServer($anywsdl);
$server->addFunction(addAllFuntions);
$server->handle();
```

Then in the same php script,

```
function Security($data){   
$UserToken=get_object_vars($data);
foreach($UserToken as $uToken){
    $credentialArray=get_object_vars($uToken);
    echo $credentialArray['Username'];
    echo $credentialArray['Password'];      
}

}
```

You would need $server->setClass($yourClass), if the Security() function was in different class.